# How to render anchor element always below button

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap 3 shopping cart contains button and a element:

```
<input type="submit" value="Lisa ostukorvi" class="btn btn-success details-addtocartbutton">
<a href="/Store/AddToWishList?Product=101033" tabindex="0" role="button" class="helper-addtowishlist">Lisa lemmikutesse</a>
```

Depending on screen resolution, a element appears in next line or immendiately after button

How to force a element to appear always below button:

[image]

Comment: To get a proper answer we need more that just 2 lines of code, so if you could post a minimal working code snippet so we have with what to work

Comment: Put them both in the same column...

Comment: Please add code, really need to see how you are trying to do what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the width of the button - say 100 pixels.

```
button {
   width:100px;
   float:right;
}
```

Put a clearfix div beneath your button and then you can put your anchor tag in a paragraph and set the width of it to be the same as the button

```
p a {
   width:100px;
   float:right;
}
```

If you were to float both the button and the paragraph to the right then the anchor would always be beneath the button.

Here is a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/132cyzve/3/